# How to create dialog which contains both time and date dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

Hello All I want to create a dialog from which I can set date and time together.How can I do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific? For example, provide a mockup of what you want, explain why you're needing to set the date and time, etc. It's difficult to answer a question this vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layout consisting of a DatePicker and a TimePicker in fx a LinearLayout with the orientation set to vertical.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <DatePicker android:id="@+id/datePicker1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></DatePicker>
        <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TimePicker>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then use this layout to create your dialog.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
```

To react to user interacting with your timepicker, do something like this:

```
TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)dialog.findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);
tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(myOnTimechangedListener);
```

To get the values from the date- and timepicker when the user has finished setting them, add an OK button in your dialog, and then read the date and time values from the Date- and TimePicker when the user presses OK.

Comment: I have used your code but my problem is I am not getting how to DatePicker. It does not show Method as TimePicker has (eg. setOnTimeChangedListener();) .Please Suggest me more how can I use DatePicker Also

Comment: Add an OK button in your dialog, and then read the date values from the DatePicker when the user presses OK. The methods to use are getDayOfMonth(), getMonth() and getYear().

Answer (score 2):

create a dialog with two clickable views to show datePicker and Timepicker .

Comment: I want to use both date and time view in a same dialog view

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to create a simple input box, and then parse the date/time provided.  If you give the user a hint as to the formatting that might make your life easier.

```
Toast(...."Please enter the date/time (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)"...).show();
String datetime = findViewById(R.id.datetime_input);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
Date date = formatter.parse(datetime);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for reply but this wasn't I am looking for.